# iAd not showing on Device after releasing application on App Store

Tags: iphone, ios, iad

Checked couple of questions regarding not showing iAd after releasing application on App Store.

Make all necessary settings for iAd, The test ads are showing fine in simulator and Device, then release application and enable iAd Network for that application.

In iAd Network Section, the status shows as "Live Ads" and requests are increasing every day.

When click on that application, the status is as "Live: This app is receiving live ads. You have not configured ad preferences for this app." anything i am missing?

On which email-id to contact apple?

please help....

Answer (score 3):

It depends, first, from AppStore country where you App was bought by user, and, second from country from where user runs your app.
As stated here http://developer.apple.com/iad: iAd advertisements are currently being served to apps on the U.S., U.K., Germany, Italy, Spain, France, and Japan App Stores.