# iAd not showing on Device after releasing application on App Store Italy

Tags: ios, iphone, iad

Hello guys I have a problem as stated in the question. In Italy the iAd network is available but iAds are not showing when I download my app from the App Store. In the test emulator it was working fine. It is an iPhone only app. What might be the problem?

I am aware of the duplicate question:
[iAd not showing on Device after releasing application on App Store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7440971/iad-not-showing-on-device-after-releasing-application-on-app-store), but I am sure that iAd is available in Italy.

Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Actually Ads appeared after one day. I don't know, but this was the first time I used them on an app, so I received in iTunes Connect a message that iAds were activated after one day. Maybe this helps anyone else who has this issue.

Comment: Ads still don't show in my app after more than a day. What did iTunes Connect message actually say? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry to resurrect this old question but I'm having the same problem, my app was approved on Saturday so the iAd review may happen on Monday. I was wondering, however, if your iAd Network portal reported any requests before ads started appearing, or if it just stayed at 0.

Comment: Found this in the developer guide, After your app is approved and Ready for Sale, Apple reviews it to determine the app’s appropriateness for receiving ads from iAd advertisers. When your app is approved for iAd, you’ll begin to see ad impressions within a few days. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ConfiguringStoreTechnologies.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH2-SW6

Answer (score 3):

iAd may not be displayed on your device if there is no Ad available to display targeting your device and your type of application. Even if iAd is available, there may be no advertisers that chose to launch ads that corresponds to your app

Comment: It is very weird though seeing a white strip on top of an app. Seems a  bug or bad design.

Comment: Did you follow this best practice to hide blank ad:https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2264/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011827-CH1-HIDE_BLANK_OR_EMPTY_BANNERS. Check the "Hide blank or empty banners" part

Comment: No thanks for this, it is very useful. I come from admob on android (although a long time ago) and as far as I remember this problem was not present.