# iAd Not Showing Any Ads

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, app-store, iad

My first app, Fishy Frenzy! got released on the App Store 4 days ago and I have iAd set up in my app. On the simulator all of the test apps work just fine and displayed perfectly. Then I, set up my contract with iAd and "activated" iAd for my app through iTunesConnect. iAd says it is "Live and Receiving Ads" but I have never seen any ad ran on my app and it isn't even receiving requests because on iTunesConnect everything is 0's..

Is it possible I did something wrong? The ads ran perfectly on the simulator.. I figured it might take a few days (and looking at other posts it says it could take 1-3 days) but I am on day 4 and still have no requests..

**EDIT**

Well after 5 days I finally started receiving requests! Just took some time I guess..

Comment: What country are you in? iAds are not supported in most countries.

Comment: Well it's not that then ...

Comment: Yeah I didn't think so.. I feel like I should at least have requests by now...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When the app with ads is released, it gets reviewed by the iAd team to start displaying ads. So now, the app is in review by the iAd team. The ads should show up soon. The same problem happened to me and I waited and they showed up.

Comment: Okay thank you! It's going on day 5 now still with 0 requests so hopefully it will appear sometime soon..

Answer (score 3):

For others having similar problem:

The iAds review process seems to be disconnected from the AppStore. I had one app that was approved and ready to serve live ads.

[image]

But no requests were coming, even after waiting the suggested 4-5 days. After communicating with Apple, it turned out the app has been classified as “designed for children” and therefore not allowed to serve iAds (according to the iAds policy https://developer.apple.com/support/appstore/iad-app-network/).

Summary: It could be that your app was not approved by iAds (even if was approved for AppStore). No one will tell you until you contact Apple.

Comment: What was the rating of your app? Did you check the Designed for Children checkbox? Because I have an app with a rating of 4+ but I never checked the Designed for Children, and I'm wondering if I would come across the same issue.

Comment: Mine was 4+ but not checked "Made for kids". I _think_ the approval process for iAds is separate from the AppStore approval and might take another decision - so you might hit this problem.

Answer (score 1):

First Make sure you've filled out the correct application in iTunes Connect for your application to utilize iAd.

Second iAds are not supported in many countries.

Third As FreeFire said it takes some time to get reviewed, so you can wait for some time.

Fourth iAd may not be displayed on your device if there is no Ad available to display targeting your device and your type of application. Even if iAd is available, there may be no advertisers that chose to launch ads that corresponds to your app.

the fourth one as explained by slecorne here..
https://stackoverflow.com/a/20396589/1865424

Comment: 1.) I think I have filled out everything, especially since iAd says I have "live, running ads" 2.) I am in US so that should be supported 3.) I hope this is the correct answer since it's been 5 days now.. 4.) Even with this true, wouldn't I at least be getting requests? I have 0..

Comment: According to my knowledge these are 4 situations which can create problem, Please verify it again.

Comment: I will wait it out another day or two which would give it a week.. If it says that the ads are "Live and Running" does that mean they already approved it on their end?

Comment: yup and incase if its not showing try to ask this question on apple developer site, they may told you the exact reason.

Comment: Okay I will go try asking there also. I emailed iAd and they were no help at all..

Comment: when you mailed them? hope they will get back to you soon.

Answer (score 0):

My App went live last April 12, the Ads started showing up April 14. I did ask iAds tech support and their answer is "When your App is Ready for sale, your app will be reviewed for iAd.......". So if you still don't get any ads, email the iAds support. good luck

Answer (score -2):

iAds are no more available for new apps.

> **iAd App Network will be Discontinued
>   January 15, 2016**
>
> The iAd App Network will be discontinued as of June 30, 2016. Although
>   we are no longer accepting new apps into the network, advertising
>   campaigns may continue to run and you can still earn advertising
>   revenue until June 30. If you’d like to continue promoting your apps
>   through iAd until then, you can create a campaign using iAd Workbench.
>   We will continue to keep you updated, but if you have any questions,
>   contact us.

https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=01152016a

Comment: That's actually not true. It's just badly worded. What Apple mean is that you no longer can make ads for your apps in iAd. iAd will continue to serve ads inside of your apps, just that the ads themselves won't be advertising other apps.

Comment: Thanks Jacob Joz, But my app was not showing ads even though they were approved. I contacted apple and I got the reply from Apple stating this 
"New apps are no longer being accepted into the iAd App Network program"

Comment: They also said   "Developers have more expertise and choice than ever before on ways to make money from the apps they create. As a result, the need for Apple to provide full-service ad monetization has diminished. Instead, we will focus on new ways to help developers with promotion and distribution"

Comment: Yep, it's definitely confusing. I read this article: http://9to5mac.com/2016/01/15/apple-will-discontinue-iad-app-network-for-developers-on-june-30th/