# Live app not showing iAd on development device

Tags: iad

I've added my iPhone to my development devices list. I've tested iAd on the simulator and device while in development and a test iAd banner is successfully shown. But, when I download my released app from the App Store it does not show live ads.

Are live ads not shown on development devices?

Comment: Have you deleted your developer version of your application from your device and installed the distributed version of your application from the App Store?

Comment: yes, i removed. Are Apple blocked real iad in developer device?

Answer (score 0):

Actually Ads appeared after one day. I don't know, but this was the first time I used them on an app, so I received in iTunes Connect a message that iAds were activated after one day. Maybe this helps anyone else who has this issue.
Ref: [iAd not showing on Device after releasing application on App Store Italy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20396211/iad-not-showing-on-device-after-releasing-application-on-app-store-italy)

Comment: check your device is jailbreak or not?

Comment: no, Now my device not jailbreak... before I don't know. but my friend with jb device still show iad :)))

Comment: can you uninstall the app from your device and install it again and then check.

Comment: any info from apple will blocked iad from developer device or jb device?